# Pytorch LSTM loss constant

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I am using Pytorch to train a bilateral LSTM model for sequence labeling. During the training loop, the loss remains constant through all epochs.

After some debugging, I discovered that the `grad` attribute is always `None`, even after the first `loss.backward()` call. As such, the optimizer can't update the gradients and, consequently, the model doesn't learn anything.
How can I fix this issue in order for backpropagation to happen correctly?

This is the class that I used to define the model:

```
class biLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_matrix, embedding_size,
                 pad_idx,
                 learning_rate,
                 n_classes):
        super(biLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.lstm_layer_size = 64
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.embedding_matrix = embedding_matrix
        self.num_layers = 1
        self.n_classes = n_classes



        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.embedding_size, 
                            self.lstm_layer_size, 
                            bidirectional=True,
                            batch_first=True) #input is given in shape (batch_size, seq_len, emb_len, dropout=0.05)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.lstm_layer_size * 2, self.n_classes)

        self.hidden = None

    def forward(self, x):
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        logits = self.fc(lstm_out)
        return logits

    def init_state(self, x):
        self.hidden = (torch.zeros(self.num_layers * 2, x.size(0), self.lstm_layer_size).to(device),
                torch.zeros(self.num_layers * 2, x.size(0), self.lstm_layer_size).to(device))
```

In this network, I don´t need the embedding layer, as the input given to the network is already in the shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_size)`.

The training loop used is the following:

```
model = biLSTM(embedding_matrix, EMBEDDING_SIZE, words_idx[PADDING_CLASS], learning_rate, n_classes)
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() # CrossEntropyLoss applies log_softmax 
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

def init_weights(m): #initialize weigths according to a normal distribution
    for name, param in m.named_parameters():
        nn.init.normal_(param.data, mean = 0, std = 0.1)
        param.requires_grad = True

    
model.apply(init_weights)

def train_model(model, train: pd.DataFrame):
    model.train()
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        losses = []
        epoch_loss = 0.0

        for (sentence, label) in train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            model.init_state(sentence)

            logits = model(sentence)

            classes = torch.argmax(logits, dim=2)

            loss = loss_function(classes.double(), label.double())           
            loss.backward()
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            losses.append(loss.item())
            optimizer.step()
            

        print("Epoch: %d, loss: %1.5f, accuracy: %d" % (epoch+1, epoch_loss/sentence.size(0), categorical_accuracy(classes, label, words_idx[PADDING_CLASS])))

train_model(model, train)
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to find the error - I was passing the output of `argmax` to the `loss_function`, which has a gradient always equal to 0.

However, my LSTM is still not performing as expected. For this sequence labeling task, it achieves categorical accuracy of approximately 50% after 20 epochs.
I am not sure what is wrong with the network, as it seems to be well-implemented according to several online tutorials.

Comment: The gradient of `argmax` is always zero, you should be providing `logits` CrossEntropyLoss (see [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) for details). The correct usage depends on what `label` is. Is it an index tensor, a one-hot tensor, or a distribution? Since you didn't provide the definition of your dataset we can't know for sure, but more often than not `label` is an index tensor (of type `LongTensor`), in which case the correct usage would be `loss = loss_function(logits, label)`.

Comment: @jodag You were right. I can't provide the `argmax` output directly to the loss function. I made the one-hot-encoder for the labels to have the same shape as the logits. Anyway, the **loss** is now decreasing. However, the performance of the network is still really poor (approximately 50% after 20 epochs).

Comment: Glad to know you solved the issue. Perhaps instead of an update to the question, you could post the solution as an answer and accept it so this question doesn't show in unanswered filters. Your LSTM performance issue seems more appropriate to be asked in e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/.